# Structs that refer to each other

Tags: c, gcc

I want to have two structs that can contain each other. Here is an example:

```
struct a {
  struct b bb;
};

struct b {
  struct a aa;
};
```

But this code doesn't compile. gcc says:

```
test.c:3: error: field ‘bb’ has incomplete type
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

How is that supposed to work? `a` would contain `b`, which would contain `a`, which would contain `b`, etc...

I suppose you want to use a pointer instead?

```
struct b;

struct a {
  struct b *bb;
};

struct b {
  struct a *aa;
};
```

Even that though is bad coding style - circular dependencies should be avoided if possible.

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily bad style - after all, a simple linked list `struct` will contain a pointer to itself, which is even more circular.

Comment: @detly: I'm referring to circular dependencies, i.e. two classes depending on each other or pointing to each other. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency

Comment: @sjf - Go to the drawing board and look at how your structure is supposed to look like. 'b' essentially contains an `a`, but `a` contains a `b`. What do you expect to end up in memory? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Okay, let me try an analogy here. You're putting a box into a bucket, and you're putting the bucket into the box. Picture that.

Comment: You will have at least 1 pointer (technically, struct b can contain a, not necessarily a*) .

Answer (score 9):

```
struct a;
struct b;

struct a{
   struct b *bb;
};

struct b{
   struct a *aa;
};
```

Most of the header file declare the structure before defining its members. Structure definition will be defined in somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way of dealing with this is to make them pointers and then dynamically allocate them or even just assign the pointer from the address of a static instance of the other struct.

```
struct a {
  struct b *bb;
};

struct b {
  struct a *aa;
};

struct a a0;
struct b b0;

void f(void) {
  a0.bb = &b0;
  b0.aa = &a0;
}
```

I would suggest, however, that you look for a tree-structured organization. Perhaps both objects could point to a common third type.

Answer (score 0):

This is nonsensical.

Imagine if you say that every `X` contains a `Y` and every `Y` contains an `X`, then inside each `X` is a `Y` which in turn contains an `X`, which in turn contains a `Y`, which in turn contains an `X`, *ad infinitum*.

Instead, you can have an `X` contain a *reference to* or (or *pointer to*) a `Y` and vice-versa.

Comment: That's not necessarily true. The pointer to either struct may be at a point, be set as NULL, and handled by a relevant function, terminating the supposed loop.