# Typedef'ed structs that have pointers to each other

Tags: c, typedef

Ansi C allows that two different structs can contain pointers to each other (also shown in [structs-that-refer-to-each-other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394079/structs-that-refer-to-each-other)). I know that this is not a good idea in many circumstances, but that's not the question here. Is it possible to achieve the same using typedef'ed structs?

The code below works just fine.

```
struct b;
typedef struct a {
    struct b *bb;
} A;
typedef struct b {
    struct a *aa;
} B;
```

But using type "B" it fails

```
typedef struct b B;
typedef struct a {
    B *bb;
} A;
typedef struct b {
    A *aa;
} B;
```

with

> error: redefinition of typedef ‘B’

Is it possible to tell the compiler that ‘B’ will be declared later and use it in the definition of A?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this instead:

```
typedef struct a A;
typedef struct b B;

struct a {
    B *bb;
};
struct b {
    A *aa;
};
```

Does this work for you ?

Comment: Could you explain why I have this error using this method ? redifition of typedef 'A' previsous declaration of 'A' was here ?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you already typedef'd it.

You should do something like this:

```
struct a;
struct b;
typedef struct a A;
typedef struct b B;
```

And then you can define struct a and b and use a,b,A*,B* in the definitions of a and b

Comment: Note that the first two lines are redundant but arguably clearer.