# C field has incomplete type

Tags: c, struct, typedef, heading

I have the folowing header file :

```
 #ifndef SERVER_STRUCTURES_H
 #define SERVER_STRUCTURES_H

typedef struct game {
  int id;
  struct player player1;
  struct player player2;
  struct game *next;
} game_t;

typedef struct player {
  int id;
  int score;
  struct player *player1;
  struct game *g ;
} player_t;

#endif
```

I get the error: field 'player1' has incomplete type struct player player1

and

field 'player2' has incomplete type struct player player2.

What is the mistake? thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Structs that refer to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394079/structs-that-refer-to-each-other)

Comment: `struct player` is an incomplete type from the beginning until the closed brace of its definition. You cannot declare a variable or a struct field of an incomplete type. That's the mistake.

Comment: Pick your text-book and search for the term *forward declaration*. And think about the order in which you define things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declarations must be before where they are used, so the two declarations should be swapped.
To allocate `player1` and `player2`, the compiler will require the full declaration of `struct player`.

Then, you should tell the compiler that `struct game` will be declared later.
It is enough information to create "pointer to something".

```
#ifndef SERVER_STRUCTURES_H
#define SERVER_STRUCTURES_H

struct game;

typedef struct player {
  int id;
  int score;
  struct player *player1;
  struct game *g ;
} player_t;

typedef struct game {
  int id;
  struct player player1;
  struct player player2;
  struct game *next;
} game_t;

#endif
```